# error when compiling giza 1.0.5

Tags: c++, linux, makefile, giza++

I'm currently trying to compile GIZA++ which I downloaded from http://code.google.com/p/giza-pp/downloads/detail?name=giza-pp-v1.0.5.tar.gz. But everytime I run the make command, the following error always happened:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lstdc++
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lm
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lc
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [GIZA++] Error 1
```

I really don't know what is wrong, can anyone help me?

I'm using Fedora 14 with g++ version 4.5.1

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

The linker is saying it cannot find the C++ libraries. This suggests that there is something wrong with your GCC installation. Can you post the command line that you use to compile your code. also, can you try compiling this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {   
    cout << "hello" << endl;
}
```

Save it into a file called `hello.cpp`, and then compile it:

```
g++ hello.cpp
```

and tell us what errors you get if any.

Comment: Thx for your quick reply, the full command line used when compiling the giza is this:

http://goo.gl/kkGxi

I also tried the hello.cpp and no error happened. So what do you think I should do?

Comment: @ndriks If the code I provided compiled and linked, your compiler and libraries must be there. This suggests that there is something fishy about the environment you are running the GIZA build in. Is it from a makefile, a script?

Comment: @neil-butterworth yes, it is from a makefile, which included in the GIZA source code. If that is the case, how can I fix it?

Comment: The makefile looks ok - I'm afraid I can't suggest anything else. Your best bet is probably to raise an issue on the project's Google Code page.